# Yii Framework: Multiple AJAX Paginators

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii, pagination

I'm working on an Yii application and I have a particular action that renders a page which is separated in 3 different sections. Let's say that the first section displays items from the database from Class A, the second displays items from Class B and the third from Class C. Each class section is in different div and each section could contain a lot of items.

My goal though is to display only 8 or 10 items per section from the respective class and then provide paginator links to navigate to the rest of the section's items. I have all the items in three different arrays and I can display them with no problems, however, without the pages functionality. In a nut shell, I need to somehow make 3 different paginators work on the same page and I have no idea how reading the yii pagination guides so any tips are more than welcome. Thank you!

Comment: I've tried using the CPagination class, however, I'm unable to tie it with a single section, let's say a div on the page. I pretty much copied the code here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination I'm assuming that I'll have to do something a bit more complicated using ajax or something of the sort.

Comment: And you don't want to use a CGridView or a CListView?

Comment: Doesn't matter as long as I can make it work.

Comment: Then look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView where you can use ajax out of the box. Depending on what you want to achieve you might be interrested in http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView

Answer (score 1):

I think that you had forget the pageVar in your [CPagination](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination).